# connected path manifold is connected

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, connectedness, path-connected

Is this proof correct?

Suppose $M$ is not connected. Then $M$ is disjoint union of two non empty open sets $U$ and $V$. Take $x\in U$, $y \in V$ joined by a path $\gamma:[0,1]\rightarrow M$.

$\gamma([0,1])$ is partitioned by wether an element is in $U$ or in $V$.

If there are more then on interval in $U$ and in $V$, again, restrict $\gamma$ and redefine $x\in U$ and $y\in V$ if necessary. i.e. $\gamma([0,\epsilon])\subset U$ and $\gamma(]\epsilon,1])\in V$ or $\gamma([0,\epsilon[)\subset U$ and $\gamma([\epsilon,1])\in V$.

But then, in the first case, $\gamma^{-1}(V) = ]\epsilon,1]$ which is a contradiction since $V$ is open and $]\epsilon,1]$ is closed. In the second case, $\gamma^{-1}(U) = [0,\epsilon[$ which is a contradiction since $U$ is open and $[0,\epsilon[$ is closed.

Comment: I'm messing things up I'll remove that :)

Comment: $]\epsilon , 1]$ and $[0, \epsilon[$ are open sets in $[0,1]$. However, you are on the right track. What can you tell about  $\gamma^{-1}(U) \cup \gamma^{-1}(V)$?

Comment: Sorry I ment $\gamma^{-1}(U) = [0,\epsilon]$ is closed in the first case and $\gamma^{-1}(V) = [\epsilon,1]$ which is closed in the second case. And these two cases give us our contradictions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Path-Connected implies Connected without knowing that \[0,1\] is connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/127915/path-connected-implies-connected-without-knowing-that-0-1-is-connected)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof is more simple: $[0,1]$ is partitioned into disjoint non-empty open subsets $\gamma^{-1}(U)$ and $\gamma^{-1}(V)$, which is impossible.

Comment: of course. Much simpler. thanks